# How to dial the same digit as asked in twilio incoming voice call

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I've done the basic twillio client setup following instructions here - https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/incoming-calls

Would it be possible to reply the voice call with the digit asked to dial ?

Like, if the automated call asks to press 5, I can respond with pressing digit 5, like that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have your gather code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="/process_gather.php" timeout="10" finishOnKey="*">
        <Say>Please enter a digit</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Then on process_gather.php capture the gathered input and send it back to the user using

```
<Response>
 <Say>You pressed <?php echo  $_REQUEST['Digits']; ?></Say>
</Response>
```

Comment: Also I want to reply that incoming voice call by pressing the digit asked to.

Comment: Sorry I missed that, so just to clarify you are dialing a number and passing the digits pressed by the caller? Caller calls in press some numbers then you forward the call and pass those digits?